# sort associative arrays in multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Is there a way to sort this array by the value of "displayName" key?
I'm trying to understand the usort with no luck
Any help would much appreciated

```
Array
(
    [totalCount] => 3
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [displayName] => LDN
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [displayName] => AMS
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [displayName] => CGN
                )

        )

)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: From the linked question/answer, replace the key that you want to use to sort - `usort($myArray['results'], function($a, $b) { return $a['displayName'] <=> $b['displayName']; });`

Comment: Thank you very much :)